# How to move sublist inside item values

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I want to add the sublist inside item:

My source xml:

```
<body>
<p>blahblah</p>
<ul outputclass="l1">
<li outputclass="lt1">blahblah</li>
<li outputclass="lt1">blahblah</li>
<li outputclass="lt1">blahblah
  <ul outputclass="l2">
  <li outputclass="lt2">blahblah</li>
  <li outputclass="lt2">blahblah<fn><p>blah</p></fn></li>
  <li outputclass="lt2">blahblah
    <ul outputclass="l3">
    <li outputclass="lt3">blahblah<fn><p>blah</p></fn></li>
    <li outputclass="lt3">blahblah</li>
    <li outputclass="lt3">blahblah</li>
    </ul></li>
  </ul></li>
<li outputclass="lt1">blahblah</li>
<li outputclass="lt1">blahblah</li>
</ul>
<p>blahblah</p>
</body>
```

myxslt

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <para>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </para>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fn">
    <footnote>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </footnote>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ul[@outputclass='l1']">
    <itemizedlist type="&#x2022;">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </itemizedlist>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ul[@outputclass='l2']">
    <itemizedlist type="&#x2022;">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </itemizedlist>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ul[@outputclass='l3']">
    <itemizedlist type="&#x2022;">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </itemizedlist>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="li[@outputclass='lt1']">
    <item><para>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </para></item>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="li[@outputclass='lt2']">
    <item><para>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </para></item>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="li[@outputclass='lt3']">
    <item><para>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </para></item>
  </xsl:template>
```

output i am getting para closing at the end of the sub list needed as para closing after sublist:

```
<body>
<para>blahblah</para>
<itemizedlist type="&#x2022;">
<item><para>blahblah</para></item>
<item><para>blahblah</para></item>
<item><para>blahblah
  <itemizedlist type="&#x2022;">
  <item><para>blahblah</para></item>
  <item><para>blahblah<footnote><p>blah</p></footnote></para></item>
  <item><para>blahblah
    <itemizedlist type="&#x2022;">
    <item><para>blahblah<footnote><p>blah</p></footnote></para></item>
    <item><para>blahblah</para></item>
    <item><para>blahblah</para></item>
    </itemizedlist></para></item>
  </itemizedlist></para></item>
<item><para>blahblah</para></item>
<item><para>blahblah</para></item>
</itemizedlist>
<para>blahblah</para>
</body>
```

but needed output as like sublist should be between para closing and item closing as shown below :

```
<body>
<para>blahblah</para>
<itemizedlist type="&#x2022;">
<item><para>blahblah</para></item>
<item><para>blahblah</para></item>
**<item><para>blahblah</para>**
  <itemizedlist type="&#x2022;">
  <item><para>blahblah</para></item>
  <item><para>blahblah</para></item>
  **<item><para>blahblah<footnote><p>blah</p></footnote></para>**
    <itemizedlist type="&#x2022;">
    <item><para>blahblah<footnote><p>blah</p></footnote></para></item>
    <item><para>blahblah</para></item>
    <item><para>blahblah</para></item>
    **</itemizedlist></item>**
  **</itemizedlist></item>**
<item><para>blahblah</para></item>
<item><para>blahblah</para></item>
</itemizedlist>
<para>blahblah</para>
</body>
```

Is it possible as bolded one.
If possible please suggest me

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you simply want to use `apply-templates` inside of the `li` elements and then wrap any non-whitespace text nodes into `para` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <para>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </para>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ul[@outputclass='l1']">
        <itemizedlist type="&#x2022;">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </itemizedlist>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ul[@outputclass='l2']">
        <itemizedlist type="&#x2022;">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </itemizedlist>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ul[@outputclass='l3']">
        <itemizedlist type="&#x2022;">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </itemizedlist>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li[@outputclass='lt1']">
        <item>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li[@outputclass='lt2']">
        <item>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li[@outputclass='lt3']">
        <item>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li/text()[normalize-space()]">
        <para>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </para>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you @Martin Honnen its working, but one listitem inside footnote element text is there that i need inside para can you suggest me for that.

Comment: I don't see any `footnote` element in your sample so you will need to clarify what kind of element you consider a `footnote`.

Comment: I have edited my question can you please suggest me!

Comment: Well, that is a substantial edit and a more complex input format that would rather warrant a new question, together with some explanation on the rules as to which content should be wrapped by a `para` element and which not.

Comment: i have posted as new question please see the below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45709058/need-to-add-sublist-in-between-closing-para-and-item-and-footnote-inside-closing

Comment: Hi @Martin Honnen, i have posted as new question as extension of this question please see the below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45752523/sublist-format-text-inside-label-as-attributes can you suggest me

Comment: @User515, you seem to be posting a lot of questions to related problems without showing any effort to solve the variation yourself. You have a solution to create those `num` attributes in an answer to a similar question in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44694866/252228 so try to learn from that.

Comment: That is simple para's to list format and this issue list type format to space format if you have any suggestions please give me