# Need to add sublist in between closing para and item and footnote inside closing para

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I want to add the sublist inside item and footnote text inside list para:

My source xml:

```
<body>
<p>blahblah</p>
<ul outputclass="l1">
<li outputclass="lt1">blahblah</li>
<li outputclass="lt1">blahblah</li>
<li outputclass="lt1">blahblah
  <ul outputclass="l2">
  <li outputclass="lt2">blahblah</li>
  <li outputclass="lt2">blahblah<fn><p>blah</p></fn></li>
  <li outputclass="lt2">blahblah
    <ul outputclass="l3">
    <li outputclass="lt3">blahblah<fn><p>blah</p></fn></li>
    <li outputclass="lt3">blah<fn><p>blah</p></fn>blah</li>
    <li outputclass="lt3">blahblah</li>
    </ul></li>
  </ul></li>
<li outputclass="lt1">blahblah</li>
<li outputclass="lt1">blahblah</li>
</ul>
<p>blahblah</p>
</body>
```

myxslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <para>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </para>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ul[@outputclass='l1']">
        <itemizedlist type="&#x2022;">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </itemizedlist>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ul[@outputclass='l2']">
        <itemizedlist type="&#x2022;">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </itemizedlist>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ul[@outputclass='l3']">
        <itemizedlist type="&#x2022;">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </itemizedlist>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li[@outputclass='lt1']">
        <item>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li[@outputclass='lt2']">
        <item>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li[@outputclass='lt3']">
        <item>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li/text()[normalize-space()]">
        <para>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </para>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output i am getting para closing at the end of the sub list needed as para closing after sublist:

```
<body>
<para>blahblah</para>
<itemizedlist type="&#x2022;">
<item><para>blahblah</para></item>
<item><para>blahblah</para></item>
<item><para>blahblah</para>
  <itemizedlist type="&#x2022;">
  <item><para>blahblah</para></item>
  <item><para>blahblah</para><footnote><para>blah</para></footnote></item>
  <item><para>blahblah</para>
    <itemizedlist type="&#x2022;">
    <item><para>blahblah</para><footnote><para>blah</para></footnote></item>
    **<item><para>blah</para><footnote><para>blah</para></footnote><para>blah</para></item>**
    <item><para>blahblah</para></item>
    </itemizedlist></item>
  </itemizedlist></item>
<item><para>blahblah</para></item>
<item><para>blahblah</para></item>
</itemizedlist>
<para>blahblah</para>
</body>
```

but needed output as like sublist should be between para closing and item closing and footnote inside item-para as shown below :

```
<body>
<para>blahblah</para>
<itemizedlist type="&#x2022;">
<item><para>blahblah</para></item>
<item><para>blahblah</para></item>
**<item><para>blahblah</para>**
  <itemizedlist type="&#x2022;">
  <item><para>blahblah</para></item>
  <item><para>blahblah</para></item>
  **<item><para>blahblah<footnote><para>blah</para></footnote></para>**
    <itemizedlist type="&#x2022;">
    <item><para>blahblah<footnote><para>blah</para></footnote></para></item>
    **<item><para>blah<footnote><para>blah</para></footnote>blah</para></item>**
    <item><para>blahblah</para></item>
    **</itemizedlist></item>**
  **</itemizedlist></item>**
<item><para>blahblah</para></item>
<item><para>blahblah</para></item>
</itemizedlist>
<para>blahblah</para>
</body>
```

Is it possible as bolded one.
If possible please suggest me

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't really explained which are the criteria to wrap nodes into `para`, here is a sample using `for-each-group group-adjacent="boolean(self::ul)"` to wrap any adjacent nodes not being `ul` elements into `para` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="#all">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <para>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </para>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ul[@outputclass='l1'] | ul[@outputclass='l2'] | ul[@outputclass='l3']">
        <itemizedlist type="&#x2022;">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </itemizedlist>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li[@outputclass='lt1'] | li[@outputclass='lt2'] | li[@outputclass='lt3']">
        <item>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::ul)">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <para>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="preserve"/>
                        </para>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```