# Sublist format text inside label as attributes

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I want to add the label inside para as attribute value:

My source xml:

```
<body>
<p>blahblah</p>
<ul outputclass="l1">
<li outputclass="lt1">(a) blahblah</li>
<li outputclass="lt1">(b) blahblah</li>
<li outputclass="lt1">(c) blahblah
  <ul outputclass="l2">
  <li outputclass="lt2">      (1) blahblah</li>
  <li outputclass="lt2">      (2) blahblah<fn><p>blah</p></fn></li>
  <li outputclass="lt2">      (3) blahblah
    <ul outputclass="l3">
    <li outputclass="lt3">              (i) blahblah<fn><p>blah</p></fn></li>
    <li outputclass="lt3">              (ii) blahblah</li>
    <li outputclass="lt3">              (iii) blahblah</li>
    </ul></li>
  </ul></li>
<li outputclass="lt1">(d) blahblah</li>
<li outputclass="lt1">(e) blahblah</li>
</ul>
<p>blahblah</p>
</body>
```

myxslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="#all">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <para>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </para>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ul[@outputclass='l1'] | ul[@outputclass='l2'] | ul[@outputclass='l3']">
        <itemizedlist type="&#x2022;">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </itemizedlist>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li[@outputclass='lt1'] | li[@outputclass='lt2'] | li[@outputclass='lt3']">
        <item>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::ul)">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <para>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="preserve"/>
                        </para>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output i am getting para inside labels:

```
<body>
<para>blahblah</para>
<itemizedlist type="normal">
<item><para>(a) blahblah</para></item>
<item><para>(b) blahblah</para></item>
<item><para>(c) blahblah</para>
  <itemizedlist type="normal">
  <item><para>      (1) blahblah</para></item>
  <item><para>      (2) blahblah</para></item>
  <item><para>      (3) blahblah<footnote><para>blah</para></footnote></para>
    <itemizedlist type="normal">
    <item><para>              (i) blahblah<footnote><para>blah</para></footnote></para></item>
    <item><para>              (ii) blahblah</para></item>
    <item><para>              (iii) blahblah</para></item>
    </itemizedlist></item>
  </itemizedlist></item>
<item><para>(d) blahblah</para></item>
<item><para>(e) blahblah</para></item>
</itemizedlist>
<para>blahblah</para>
</body>
```

but needed output as like para inside label values like 'A. or (A) or A) or a) or (a) or a. or i) or (i) or i.' have to be removed and add as item tag attribute num value as shown below :

```
<body>
<para>blahblah</para>
<itemizedlist type="normal">
<item num="(a)"><para>blahblah</para></item>
<item num="(b)"><para>blahblah</para></item>
<item num="(c)"><para>blahblah</para>
  <itemizedlist type="normal">
  <item num="(1)"><para>blahblah</para></item>
  <item num="(2)"><para>blahblah</para></item>
  <item num="(3)"><para>blahblah<footnote><para>blah</para></footnote></para>
    <itemizedlist type="normal">
    <item num="(i)"><para>blahblah<footnote><para>blah</para></footnote></para></item>
    <item num="(ii)"><para>blahblah</para></item>
    <item num="(iii)"><para>blahblah</para></item>
    </itemizedlist></item>
  </itemizedlist></item>
<item num="(d)"><para>blahblah</para></item>
<item num="(e)"><para>blahblah</para></item>
</itemizedlist>
<para>blahblah</para>
</body>
```

Please suggest me

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="#all">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <para>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </para>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ul[@outputclass='l1'] | ul[@outputclass='l2'] | ul[@outputclass='l3']">
        <itemizedlist type="&#x2022;">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </itemizedlist>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li[@outputclass='lt1'] | li[@outputclass='lt2'] | li[@outputclass='lt3']">
        <item>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="if(self::text()) then('text') else(generate-id())">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="self::ul">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() =  'text' and position() = 1">
                        <xsl:attribute name="num" select="tokenize(normalize-space(current-group()), ' ')[1]"/>
                        <para>
                            <xsl:value-of select="string-join(tokenize(normalize-space(current-group()), ' ')[position() > 1], ' ')"/>
                        </para>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <para>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="preserve"/>
                        </para>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </item>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```